# Obtener índice y almacenarlo en una variable en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scraping

Estoy trabajando en un ejercicio de scraping en el cual mediante el SKU debo ir a una web y traerme algunos datos (peso, alto, ancho) del producto en cuestión y luego pintarlo todo en un dataframe. Después de muchas pruebas logré hacerlo, pero al cambiar de SKU, en lugar de traerme la info de peso, largo, me trae otros datos del producto, por lo cual revisando me di cuenta que no siempre los datos que necesito estarán en la misma posición del índice que yo defino.

Actualmente con estas líneas obtengo la información en bruto del producto:

```
sku = '1081936'
url_retail = f'https://www.lider.cl/catalogo/product/sku/{sku}'

retail_page = requests.get(url_retail)

soup = BeautifulSoup(retail_page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "row"})
contents = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col"})

contents
```

Entonces se me ocurre que podría almacenar los índices de la info que necesito y guardarlos en variables para usarlas luego en una lista que utilizaría para llenar el DataFrame, pero al ser variables las posiciones según el sku, no sé como podría proceder...

Por ejemplo estuve probando así:

```
results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "row"})
contents = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col"})

datos = []

#Obtengo Los Nuemros de Indices de la lista for indices in enumerate(contents):
for indices in results:
    if "Peso" in indices.text:
        datos.append(indices)
    if "Alto" in indices.text:
        datos.append(indices)
    if "Ancho" in indices.text:
        datos.append(indices)
    if "Profundidad" in indices.text:
        datos.append(indices)
        
datos
```

Pero con un sku obtengo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando cambio de sku obtengo toda la info que necesito
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que sería mejor almacenar la información en un diccionario

Comment: ok, defino un diccionario = datos = {}, luego en el for deberia llenarlo cierto?

Comment: Así es, así estará más ordenado y también se puede crear un df con diccionarios

Comment: Utilizando este ciclo obtengo el listado de caracteristicas del producto for indices in contents:
    print(indices) , como podria llenar el diccionario?

Comment: `diccionario["key"] ="value"`

Comment: ok, obtengo lo mismo pero ya dentro del diccionario creo:  {<div class="col">Descripción</div>: <div class="col">Descripción</div>,.... pero no entiendo como proseguir, o sea como podría almacenar los índices de la info que necesito y guardarlos en variables para usarlas luego en una lista que utilizaría para llenar el DataFrame

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127693/discussion-between-nicolas-almonacid-and-christian).